# How to locate messages on Azure IoT hub?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm just starting to use the **Azure IoT Hub** and I am having trouble locating the incoming messages.

So far I believe I am successfully sending data from an Esp32 Device to the Hub.

Here are the logs from the Esp32.
[image: Esp32 Logs VsCode]

The problem is in the **portal**. I can see some messages have been received in my hub on the overview page.

In the first section, "*Messages used today*" it shows messages have been received. But in all of the other graphs, nothing is shown.

[image]

I have looked in many other places to locate the messages but have found nothing.

When using the VS code extension the events do not come through
[image]

Also using the Azure Cli on the portal no events come through
[image]

My message routing configuration at the moment is:
[image]

So somehow the messages get to the portal, but the only sign of them at all is in the first panel in the overview of the IoT hub.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There a couple of options to view the messages and other details like twin changes etc.

The easiest is to install IoTExplorer and connect it to your IoTHub:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/howto-use-iot-explorer

You can also monitor events using the Azure CLI, via 'az iot hub monitor-events' command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-iot/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_iot_az_iot_hub_monitor_events

If you are using VS Code, you can use the Azure IoT Tools extension pack to monitor events from VS Code:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.azure-iot-tools

Lastly, if you are using Visual Studio 2019, you can use the Cloud Explorer in VS to monitor events in your IoTHub

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I tried using the VS Code extension for IoT Hub. I right-clicked on my device and clicked "Start Montering Built-in Endpoint". It seems to connect but I see no events coming through, even though on the portal on the Dashboard more events are logged. Only on the 'Messages used today' cell in the first panel. They are not included in any of the graphs, just like in the image above. Also, I tried monitoring on the portal through the CLI. It says it starts the event monitor but nothing comes through after that.

Comment: Did you by any chance configure message routes in your IoT Hub?

Comment: Yes, I have two endpoint configurations in the message routing setup. I added the image in the original post above.

Comment: This all looks fine. Here are a couple of different troubleshooting steps you can try to narrow this down further:

1. Do you see messages arrive at your custom endpoint? If you disable the custom routes, do you see the messages in the CLI or VS tooling?  

2. Add your own Consumer Group under "Built-in endpoints", and specify that group with the -cg parameter in the "az iot hub monitor-events" command. Any messages showing now?

Comment: 3. If that didn't help, try connecting a simulated device to your Hub and verify if that works. This will narrow down whether it's a problem with the device code, or the Hub configuration. There are several options to do this from either CLI or a programming languages of your choice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-cli

4. Enable logging in Hub: go to 'Diagnostic settings" and enable logging for "Device Telemetry" and "Routes" - then let's see if the logs are giving us a hint on what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Stefan. After every thing though, it turns out that it was a problem with Azure itself. I purchased the basic support package and they investigated my case. They let me know they deployed a new fix and now the messages are showing up in places where they were not before.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased the basic support package and they investigated my case. They let me know they deployed a new fix and now the messages are showing up in places where they were not before.

So it seems that this was a problem with Azure itself and not something wrong I had done.